# SQL Server 2012 creating specific XML from a table

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012

I have a table `Table` with one column `ID`. It contains simple letters, let's say Table = 'A', 'B', 'C'.

I need to create an xml file which looks like this

```
<Table>
  <ID>A</ID>
  <ID>B</ID>
  <ID>C</ID>
</Table>
```

So I tried

```
select * from Table for XML AUTO, ELEMENTS
```

But this yields

```
<Table>
  <ID>A</ID>
</Table>
<Table>
  <ID>B</ID>
</Table>
<Table>
  <ID>B</ID>
</Table>
```

So as far as I understand, the inner node collection represents one single record of a table (in this case, consisting of a single field/node) and the surrounding tag indicates the record itself. But this is not what I would prefer to see.

My (quite dirty) solution converts the xml into a string, removes the

```
</Table><Table>
```

pairs and then reconstructs the XML

```
declare @x nvarchar(max)
set @x = (select id from Table for xml auto, elements)
set @x = replace(@x, '</Table><Table>', '')
select cast(@x as xml)
```

My questions is simple: Is there a correct way to achieve my goal or do I have to live with this ugly 'solution'?

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to avoid using AUTO if you want a specific output format and use PATH instead. Not tested but how about this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
FOR XML PATH('ID'), ROOT('Table')
```

Comment: Almost, but not quite right. It creates <Table><ID><ID>A</ID></ID><ID>... so an additional inner node '<ID>':-(

Comment: So, I got it! "select * from Table for XML Path(''), Root('Table')" Does the trick!

Answer (score 1):

@Dave Sexton gave me the right kick:

The solution to the above is as follows:

```
select ID 
  from Table 
   for XML Path(''), Root('Table')
```